# To show that $d(A,B) > 0$ and there exists points $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ such that $d(A,B) = d(a,b)$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $A,B$ be two non-empty, disjoint and compact subsets of a metric space $(X,d)$. To show that $d(A,B) > 0$ and there exists points $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ such that $d(A,B) = d(a,b)$.

My Proof: Since $A,B$ are non-empty disjoint and compact subsets of a metric space $(X,d)$, $A \times B$ is compact. Now we consider the set $S = \{d(x,y) \mid x \in A , y \in B \} = d(A \times B)$ and since $S$ is closed and bounded infimum of this set is within the set, i.e. there exist $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ such that $\ \ d(A,B) = \inf \{d(x,y) \mid x \in A , y \in B \}  = d(a,b)$.

Is the solution correct?

Comment: Assuming that you’ve already proved that $d$ is continuous, that continuous functions preserve compactness, and that compact subsets of $\Bbb R$ contain their infima, the argument is fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good approach but it is incomplete in an important way. You must know that the map $(a,b) \mapsto d(a,b)$ is *continuous* for the arguement to work.

Put differently it is not quite clear where "$S$ is closed and bounded" comes from.

Separately: I would also add at the very end that $d(a,b)>0$ as $A$ and $B$ are disjoint. (This is where you need disjoint; where you mention it is in fact not relevant.)

Answer (score 0):

**An other way**

Let $d(A,B)=\ell>0$.

By propriety of the infimum, there exist two sequence $(a_n)\subset A$ and $(b_n)\subset B$ that converge (respectively to $x\in X$ and $y\in X$) such that $$\lim_{n\to\infty } d(a_n,b_n)\to \ell.$$ By continuity of $(x,y)\mapsto d(x,y)$,
$$\ell=\lim_{n\to\infty }d(a_n,b_n)=d(x,y).$$
Since $A$ and $B$ are compact, $x\in A$ and $y\in B$ what conclude the proof.

Comment: "By propriety of the infimum, there exist two sequence [...] that converge" needs some justification. It is not a general property.